# Given the $ x+y+z =3$ Prove that $ x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 3xyz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given the $ x+y+z =3$ and x, y and z are positive numbers. How to prove that $ x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 3xyz$.

I tried many methods but I failed. 
I did the AM-HM in-equality, but failed.
$\frac{\frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{zx} + \frac{z}{xy}}{3} \geq \frac{3}{\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{zx}{y}} $.
The denominator of RHS of the equation must have, minimum value. So it boils down to 
$\frac{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2}{xyz} \leq 3 $. Don't know how to proceed after that.

Taking partial derivative in range $(0,3)$ for the function $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ also didn't give me the required insight. 
Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use AM-GM inequality
$$3=x+y+z\ge 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}\Longrightarrow xyz\le 1$$
and
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}=3\sqrt[3]{(xyz)^2\cdot 1}\ge\sqrt[3]{(xyz)^2\cdot(xyz)}= 3\sqrt[3]{(xyz)^3}= 3xyz$$

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. See the updated question.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

LHS= $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(\frac {x+y+z} {3}) \geq 3(xyz)^{\frac {2} {3}}.(xyz)^{\frac {1} {3}}$=RHS. (I have used here AM-GM inequality twice.)

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities, For $x,y,z > 0 \Rightarrow 3 = x+y+z \geq 3\sqrt[3]{xyz} \Rightarrow 1 = 1^3 \geq xyz \Rightarrow 3^2 = (x+y+z)^2 \leq 3(x^2+y^2+z^2) \Rightarrow 3xyz \leq 3 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \Rightarrow 3xyz \leq x^2+y^2+z^2$